# Write two metrics the same tensorboard graph - tensorflow v2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am trying to write the loss of training set and validation set every X **batches**. I wrote a karas callback based on **tensorflow v2** that calculate the values, but I cannot figure out how to put them in the same graph. Here is what I have done:

- Used two diffrent summary writers
- Used tf.summary.scalars
- Used the same tag name 'loss'

````
    def __init__(self, log_dir, train_data, validation_data, calculation_freq, num_train_batches, num_validation_batches):
        self.batch = 0
        self.train_data = train_data
        self.validation_data = validation_data
        self.calc_freq = calculation_freq
        self.num_train_batches = num_train_batches
        self.num_validation_batches = num_validation_batches
        self.log_dir = log_dir
        self.model = model
        self.eval_validation = validation_data is not None
        train_tensor_board_path = self.log_dir + '_train'
        if not os.path.exists(train_tensor_board_path):
            os.makedirs(train_tensor_board_path)

        self.train_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(train_tensor_board_path)
        self.train_writer.set_as_default()
        if self.eval_validation:
           validation_tensor_board_path = self.log_dir + '_validation'
           if not os.path.exists(validation_tensor_board_path):
               os.makedirs(validation_tensor_board_path)
           self.validation_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(validation_tensor_board_path)
           self.validation_writer.set_as_default()

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
            print('Batch number:', self.batch)
            if self.batch % self.calc_freq == 0:
                train_loss = self.model.evaluate(train_data, steps=num_train_batches)
                tf.summary.scalar('loss', float(train_loss), step=self.batch)
                self.train_writer.flush()
                if self.eval_validation:
                    validation_loss = self.model.evaluate(validation_data, steps=num_validation_batches)
                    tf.summary.scalar('loss', float(validation_loss), step=self.batch)
                    self.validation_writer.flush()

            self.batch += 1
            print('Write to tensorboard')

    def on_train_end(self, _):
        self.train_writer.close()
        if self.eval_validation:
            self.validation_writer.close()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since writes go to the *current* default summary writer [[1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/scalar)] and each summary point is associated with an integral step value, try to change the context for each of the phases (train or validation) to the current default summary writer using `with ... .as_default():`.

```py
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
            print('Batch number:', self.batch)
            if self.batch % self.calc_freq == 0:
                train_loss = self.model.evaluate(train_data, steps=num_train_batches)
                with self.train_writer.as_default(): # current default summary
                    tf.summary.scalar('loss', float(train_loss), step=self.batch)
                self.train_writer.flush()
                if self.eval_validation:
                    validation_loss = self.model.evaluate(validation_data, steps=num_validation_batches)
                    with self.validation_writer.as_default(): # current default summary
                        tf.summary.scalar('loss', float(validation_loss), step=self.batch)
                    self.validation_writer.flush()

            self.batch += 1
            print('Write to tensorboard')
```